# Collection of continuous functions determines the topology

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological space. Do the set of all $X\rightarrow X$ continuous functions uniquely determines $\tau$?

Comment: No. But the set of all continuous mapping $X\to\Bbb S$ does, where $\Bbb S$ is the Sierpiński space. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpi%C5%84ski_space#Continuous_functions_to_the_Sierpi.C5.84ski_space).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No. For example, the discrete and trivial topologies both make every function from $X$ to $X$ continuous.

Answer (score 4):

No.

let $X$ be an arbitrary set with two or more elements, and let $\tau_1$ be the discrete topology on $X$ (all sets are open), and let $\tau_2$ be the trivial topology on $X$ (only $X$ and $\emptyset$ are open).
Note that all maps **from** $(X,\tau_1)$ and all maps **into** $(X,\tau_2)$ are continuous, regardless of where they go or where they come from respectively.
Thus, in both cases, the set of all continuous maps $X\rightarrow X $ is the set of all set-theoretic maps $X\rightarrow X $, but $\tau_1 \neq \tau_2$.